# pnpm equivalent to --since option of lerna

Tags: lerna, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I'm migrating to `pnpm` to manage a monorepo from `lerna`. However, in the CI, there was a legacy command using the `--since` option of `lerna`.

```
lerna run lint --since origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME...
```

From what I understand, it allows you to run the tasks affected by the PR. What is the equivalent option for `pnpm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same option exists in `PNPM` using [--filter "[<since>]"](https://pnpm.io/filtering#--filter-since):

```bash
pnpm --filter "...[origin/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME]" lint
```